# Django, Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 55301)

Tags: python, django

I am encountering this problem when making fast requests for a Django == 4.0.5 project that I am still developing: [11 / Apr / 2023 18:50:14,703] - Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 55300). I have 1 video on my page and it takes up 3mb. However, when I make quick transitions between pages, i.e. when I create too many requests, a spinner appears and it takes time for the video to load.

I am using Django DEBUG True and not using any Nginx or WSGI Server. What is the solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

0. its an old issue with runserver https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4444
1. Serving Django with runserver is only for local development/debugging
2. if DEBUG=True in settings, django will serve uploaded media files like your movie but that is inefficient not made for production as it exposes error messages to the public. So to make performance test with that configuration is not usefull.
3. you should run django with a production server and serve media files directly from the server without passing that request to django

Comment: Hello, I think I was misunderstood. I am still in the development stage of my website and I have not uploaded it to any server yet, so I am using DEBUG True. [11/Apr/2023 18:50:14,731] - Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 55301) I am getting this error in the terminal. According to my research, setting DEBUG to False may solve the problem, but I want to understand the root cause of the issue. Honestly, I think I am experiencing this issue because I am not using Nginx or WSGI Server.

Comment: see updated answer (0)